# Is there a solution in HiveQL for joining date between start and enddate and concatenating string from a column?

Tags: sql, dataframe, hive, hiveql

[representation of the holidays data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Txj.png)

[representation of the data I want to end up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21lAS.png)

Holidays data:

| date | holidays |
| --- | --- |
| x | nan |
| y | c |
| z | b,e |
| p | d |
| r | nan |
| s | nan |
| t | a |

Startdate,enddate data:

| startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- |
| x | z |
| y | s |
| s | t+1 |

What I aim to get:

| startdate | enddate | holidays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | z | b,c,e |
| y | s | b,c,d,e |
| s | t+1 | a |

As stated in the title above, I want to know if there is a way of grouping/concatenating the holidays column in dates between without using methods like collect_list or collect_set (getting a list inside a column is not a feasible solution for me because the data size I am dealing with here is very large.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL. I explained the logic in the SQL itself - its a two step process - step1 is to calculate the holidays between dates and the step2 is to concat them.

```
select startdate , enddate , 
CONCAT_WS(',', collect_list(holidays) holidays -- This will concat holidays for a given start and end dt
from (
select h.holidays holidays,startdate , enddate 
from holidays h
join start_end_dt_table daytab on h.date between startdate and enddate  -- this subqry will give me data between start and end dt
) rs
group by startdate , enddate
```